# Unable to mock elasticsearch service in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, jestjs, nestjs

### Current behavior

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ElasticsearchService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the ElasticsearchModule context.
```

### Expected behavior

Create ElasticSearchService in test module

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { RepliesController } from './replies.controller';
import { ElasticsearchService, ElasticsearchModule } from '@nestjs/elasticsearch';
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';

describe('Replies Controller', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let elasticsearch: ElasticsearchService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ElasticsearchModule],
      controllers: [RepliesController],
      components: [ElasticsearchService, {provide: Client, useValue: {}}],
    }).compile();

    elasticsearch = module.get<ElasticsearchService>(ElasticsearchService);
  });
  it('should be defined', () => {
    const controller: RepliesController = module.get<RepliesController>(RepliesController);
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

### Environment

```
   [Nest Information]
elasticsearch version : 0.1.2
common version        : 5.4.0
core version          : 5.4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the providers using methods exposed by the test module instead of doing it in the components array:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ElasticsearchModule],
      controllers: [RepliesController]
    })
    .overrideProvider(ElasticsearchService)
    .useValue(/* your mock or whatever */)
    .compile();
```

[There are examples of this in the NestJs docs in the testing section.](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/unit-testing)